# Passing FileStream in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream

After I pass a reference of filestream from the client to the service, and the service start downloading the stream to him, how can I determine, from the client side, how much bytes were read until now (while Im using the filestream object)?

My goal is to **calculate client's upload speed** only for this file and the only way I can think of is this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How can you serialize a filestream?

Comment: Im passing it as stream object + some information about it as a massage.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: WCF can work in streaming mode, where is just sends the data as bytes. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx

Comment: I'm also surprised this is possible.  The FileStream object is neither [Serializable] or [DataContract].  Does this work because it is a subclass of Stream, which is [Serializable]?

Comment: Must be, cant find other reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend FileStream or create a wrapper for it. Override the read methods and have a counter count the bytes read.

extending (not properly implement, but should be more than enough to explain)

```
   public class CountingStream : System.IO.FileStream {

      // provide appropriate constructors

      // may want to override BeginRead too

      // not thread safe

      private long _Counter = 0;

      public override int ReadByte() {
         _Counter++;
         return base.ReadByte();            
      }

      public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count) {
         // check if not going over the end of the stream
         _Counter += count;
         return base.Read(array, offset, count);             
      }

      public long BytesReadSoFar {
         get {
            return _Counter;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Good idea. but what do you mean by "Extend FileStream or create a wrapper for it" ? Inheritance ?

Comment: Thank you. *you wrote a code after return line. mistake or am I missing here something?